# UVa 482 - Permutation Arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi i'm trying to submit UVa 482 problem [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=423):

> In many computer problems, it is necessary to permute data arrays.
>   That is, the data in an array must be re-arranged in some specified
>   order. One way to permute arbitrary data arrays is to specify the
>   permutations with an index array to point out the position of the
>   elements in the new array. Let x be an array that is to be permuted
>   and let x' be the permuted array. Then, we have the relationship
>   between x and x' that x'pi = xi.
>
> Input
>
> The input begins with a single positive integer on a line by itself
>   indicating the number of the cases following, each of them as
>   described below. This line is followed by a blank line, and there is
>   also a blank line between two consecutive inputs. Each input set will
>   contain two lines of numbers. The first line will be an index array p
>   containing the integers 1...n, where n is the number of integers in
>   the list. The numbers in the first line will have been permuted in
>   some fashion. The second line will contain a list numbers in floating
>   point format.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, the output must follow the description below. The
>   outputs of two consecutive cases will be separated by a blank line.
>   The output for this program will be the list of floating point numbers
>   from the input set, ordered according to the permutation array from
>   the input file. The output numbers must be printed one per line in the
>   same format in which they each appeared in the input file.
>
> Sample Input
>
> 1
>
> 3 1 2 
>   32.0 54.7 -2
>
> Sample Output
>
> 54.7 
>   -2 
>   32.0

but verdict result is wrong answer, problem itself is not complicated but i'm really stuck!!!
here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Main problem = new Main();
       problem.solve();
   }

   void solve() {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       int n = in.nextInt();
       int counter = 0;

       while (counter != n) {
           ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
           ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<>();

           while (in.hasNextInt())
               index.add(in.nextInt());

           for (int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
               number.add(in.next());

           String sortedNumber[] = new String[index.size()];
           for (int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
               sortedNumber[index.get(i) - 1] = number.get(i);

           for (int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
               System.out.println(sortedNumber[i]);

           if (counter < n - 1)
               System.out.println();

           counter++;
       }

       in.close();
   }
```

}

i tested for some limited inputs also, but i could not figure it out.

Comment: You need to provide the question itself as well.

Comment: sorry, i edited the link.

Comment: It should be in the question itself, not only a link. Thaught I was clear...

Comment: thanks for adding, what about problem itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that no floating-point number is also an integer. If it is, your program does weird things.

Try this input:

```
2
1 2 3
0 2.0 3.0
1 2 3
1.1 2.2 3.3
```

You should have read permutations line-by-line:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
for (String s : line.split(" ")) {
    index.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

instead of

```
// fails when there's starting ints in the "floating-point" line
while (in.hasNextInt()) index.add(in.nextInt());
```